# SQL Select statement how to return emoji

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a query where I want to select cake:

```
SELECT ''
```

But upon executing query, it gives me an output of `'??'`

How to output the real cake?

Comment: [SQL Query Where Column = '' returning Emoji characters  and ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551528/sql-query-where-column-returning-emoji-characters-and)

Answer (score 3):

set as unicode using the N'' notation

```
SELECT N''
```

Comment: @Manjay then accept this answer, i.e. click on the big, gray tick mark next to the answer.