# Why is SQL like returning both 2010 and 010 when searched with - where columnName like N'%ဲ010%'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, collation

I have a SQL column - `Comments` - which holds `nvarchar` data.

Along with the usual English characters, I can see that there are values that look like special characters, following is an example - I cannot make sense of how they got there and what they mean:

[image]

I tried to filter all values that contain that character using the following SQL but it returns 2010 as well as the one where there is a special character in place of 2.

```
where comments like N'%ဲ010%'
```

Comment: Please tag with the actual SQL database you are using.  Then, give us some sample input data in the form a table.

Comment: `like N'%ဲ010%'` this means if the value contains the given pattern of string

Comment: Yes why would it return 2010? That special character is same as 2?

Comment: verify your special character and try to get ASCII code of it, it is correct or not.

Comment: How to verify and get the ASCII code for it?

Comment: what collation are you using? probably the same as this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171331/why-does-searching-for-like-n-match-any-unicode-character-and-n-match or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551803/73226

Comment: By database is using: Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: If you do `like N'%ဲ010%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI ` this should resolve it. Presumably [MYANMAR VOWEL SIGN AI](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1032/index.htm) wasn't weighted in that earlier collation

Comment: How did that character arrive in the database? And how do I handle such characters?

Comment: We can't tell you how they got into your database. Maybe the user entered them or maybe you have a bug in code that you haven't shown us. Regarding how to "handle" them. Depends what you mean by handling them. Applying a `COLLATE` clause as above to queries trying to specifically work with that character will probably be a part of it

Comment: variable: @MartinSmith is correct regarding that character U+1032 doesn't have a sort weight defined in the version 80 collation that you're using (i.e. `Latin1_General_CI_AI`). Even testing with the next version of collations, `Japanese_90_CI_AI`, shows that it has no sort weight: `SELECT 1 WHERE NCHAR(0x1032) = NCHAR(0x0000) COLLATE Japanese_90_CI_AS; SELECT 2 WHERE NCHAR(0x1032) = N'' COLLATE Japanese_90_CI_AS;`. No sort weight means it's completely ignored. And yes, starting in the version 100 collations it (and many others that were previously missing) does have a sort weight.

Comment: variable: also, I have an idea on how the data got there, but I need to see the bytes of the entire string that contains the "special" character. Please update the question with the output of the following query, assuming it's not too long: 

`SELECT TOP (2) CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [comments]) FROM dbo.{TableName} WHERE [comments] LIKE N'%' + NCHAR(0x1032) + N'%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;`